# How I understand ENTRYPOINT logging using Flask inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

My Docker container run gunicorn, which points to "myapp.py", which is using the flask.

```
cat Dockerfile:

FROM python:3.7

<snip no important>

USER nobody
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/flask-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

flask-docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp:app -c /local/gunicorn.conf.py
```

All work good!

Docker daemon logging set to 'json/file'. I tell gunicorn log to stdout (vers 20 it is default). I can send logs from myapp.py to 'docker logs' with simple logging statements. Why this is?

```
ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nobody       1     0  0 22:01 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/flask-docker-entrypoint.sh
nobody      12     1  0 22:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp:app -c /external/
nobody      15    12  0 22:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp:app  -c /external/
nobody      57     0  7 22:44 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
nobody      62    57  0 22:44 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -e
```

flask-docker-entrypoint.sh is pid 1 so that log to stdout. Get that. Do all children of pid using entrypoint also inherit ability to log to stdout? Seems gunicorn is not pid 1 and myapp.py is not pid 1, but both log to stdout?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior in Unix-like environments is for a process to inherit its parent's stdout (and stdin and stderr).  You can demonstrate this in your local shell easily enough:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# This is script1
./script2
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# This is script2
echo hi there
```

```sh
$ ./script1
hi there
$ ./script1 > log
$ cat log
hi there
```

In the last example, if `script1`'s output goes to the console or is redirected into a log file, when it runs `script2` as a subprocess it inherits that same stdout.

The reason `gunicorn` isn't pid 1 is because you have a shell wrapper.  You can use the [exec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20) shell built-in to replace the shell process with the thing it wants to run

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp:app -c /local/gunicorn.conf.py
```

Unless you need to do more setup, it might be simpler to put the command directly into the Dockerfile.  (`CMD` is easier to override at runtime to do things like get debugging shells if you need to; this replaces your existing `ENTRYPOINT` line.)

```sh
CMD ["gunicorn", "myapp:app", "-c", "/local/gunicorn.conf.py"]
```

Comment: many thanks David-san. Why myappy.py writes to docker logs? It is not a process. Is it because gunicorn 'hooks' into it and it now 'inside' the gunicorn?